# How does captive.apple.com force the captive login page when other websites don’t?

Tags: iphone, networking

Lots of hotel, coffee shop, etc. networks require accepting a ToS via a captive page. Sometimes when I join these networks I can’t get that captive page to show by just going to regular websites - the requests just time out. But I can always get it to show by going to captive.apple.com. What does this do differently that other websites aren’t doing to force the captive page?

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13369038) suggests that captive pages are triggered by an http request but not an https request -- or maybe not an http request that the destination website redirects to https. I'm not sure if it's the http-to-https redirect or the mere fact of using https that's the problem. You could test that by entering a URL including the https scheme and seeing if that triggers the captive page.

Anyway, I thought it was odd that whenever the captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html URL was given, it was with the http scheme, but it makes sense after reading this.